# Change Bootstrap's navbar breakpoint from sass

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I change the default breakpoint for Bootstrap navigation from sass, so the hamburger menu to appear on `max-width: 992px` ?

Comment: Have you tried `@media` query?

Comment: I don't want to override it, I just want to change the default one from sass. :)

Comment: Bootstrap 3 or 4?

Answer (score 0):

when you download your boostrap bundle, there is an option that lets you customize it: colors, breakpoints, etc:

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/